# cannot install library python

Tags: python, telethon

i want to install the library `telethon`

It says i should execute this line of code

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade telethon
```

The first command works, it has a bunch of warnings but it seems to work.

But the second command says:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement telethon (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for telethon`

So what i am doing wrong?

I am using windows

Comment: What version of Python are you using? According to [Telethon's setup.py file](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/45ed6658fe6829f0efe6196dc91adb797e802daa/setup.py#L226) it only supports 3.5 - 3.8

Comment: @DeepSpace well when i type in `python -V` it says Python 2.7.15. I tried to upgrade python but i dont know how it works exactly since i am pretty new to python

Comment: You should be doing `python3 -V`

Comment: @DeepSpace well then 3.9.6

Comment: Then here is your problem. As already explained, Telethon can only be installed (in an official way at least) on Python 3.5 - 3.8

Comment: @DeepSpace so how do i fix this problem could you give me an hint?

Comment: Install a compatible version of Python and use a virtual environment. If you don't know how to, research it. This is out of scope for this question

Comment: I'm using 3.9 and it's just fine

Comment: What happens if you do `python3 -m pip -V`?

Comment: @Qwerty-Space it says pip 21.1.1

Answer (score 0):

To install a virtual env and your package:

```sh
$ python --version
Python 3.6.9

$ python -m venv venv

$ source venv/bin/activate

(venv)$ pip install -U pip setuptools
(venv)$ pip install telethon
(venv)$ python

Python 3.6.9 (default, Jun 13 2020, 20:27:45)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Now try to load `telethon`:

```
>>> import telethon

>>> telethon.__version__
'1.23.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

I just have to run VS code editor as "admin"